# Should I use its()?

Tags: rspec

Rspecs `its` function has been abstracted out into a [separate gem](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-its).

Is this merely to help the developers of rspec keep organized? Or is `its` considered a code smell?

```
describe '#initialize' do
    subject{ location = Location.new(longitude: 123423, latitude: 444421) }

    its(:longitude).should eq 123423
    its(:latitude).should eq 444421
end
```

If `its` is a smell, how should I write the above?

Answer (score 0):

The developers removed `its` in Rspec 3 because according to them, `its` often [leads to documentation output that is essentially lies](https://gist.github.com/myronmarston/4503509)

Consider something like this (general example that you'll have to adapt to your specific needs):

```
describe '#conditions_apply_to?' do
  let(:product){ Fabricate :product }
  it 'returns false when combining with other conditions' do
    subject.conditions_combination_operator = 'and'
    expect(subject.conditions_apply_to?(product)).to be_false
  end
end
```